# Concordance of three variables in R and plot the data

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `mydf`. There are three sets of columns represented as `app`, `ora` and `pin`. I want to match or compare all column values with app vs ora, ora vs pin and pin vs app columns and get the concordance/match statistics. I also want to get the overall concordance between the three variables and make plots to represent the data. what is the best way to do this in R?

```
 mydf<-structure(c("0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", 
                      "0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/1", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", "0/0", 
                      "0/0", "0/1"), .Dim = c(3L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("1", "2", 
                                                                          "4"), c("app:x", "ora:x", "pin:x", "app:y", "ora:y", "pin:y")))
```

Comment: We're going to need more info.  Let's start with how you want to compare these values?  They are character data, so the only possibility is to determine if they are identical or not.  Is that what you intended?  And there are 6 columns.  Can you clarify which columns are to be compared?

Comment: @BryanHanson yes that comparison is basically based on string match. I may have 3*n number of columns with the set of `app`, `ora` and `pin` columns I want to compare, so this is a cumulative comparison. I just want to see their overall concordance.

Comment: How does app:x fit with app:y ? Are they to be compared? Pooled?  Does LukeA answer work?

Comment: @BryanHanson Yes luke's combinatorial comparison (`app` vs `ora`, `ora` vs `pin` and `pin` vs `app`) is correct, but I also want overall comparison (i.e. `app` vs`ora` vs `pin`).

Comment: @BryanHanson Yes `app:x` should be compared with `app:y`.. to `app:n` th term.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's one approach as a starter (possibly much room for optimization, as I'm not that familiar with the data.table package):

```
library(splitstackshape)
dt <- cSplit(melt(cSplit(mydf, 1:6, "/")[, rowname:=rownames(mydf)], id.vars = c("rowname")), 2, ":")[]
setkey(dt, rowname, variable_2)
dt <- dt[dt, allow.cartesian=TRUE][variable_1!=i.variable_1]
idx <- which(!duplicated(cbind(dt$rowname,dt$variable_2, t(apply(dt[, .(variable_1, i.variable_1)], 1, function(x) sort(x))))))
dt <- dt[idx, .(rowname, variable_2, variable_1, i.variable_1, isEqual=value==i.value)]
dt
#     rowname variable_2 variable_1 i.variable_1 isEqual
#  1:       1        x_1        ora          app    TRUE
#  2:       1        x_1        pin          app    TRUE
#  3:       1        x_1        pin          ora    TRUE
#  4:       1        x_2        ora          app    TRUE
#  5:       1        x_2        pin          app    TRUE
#  6:       1        x_2        pin          ora    TRUE
#  7:       1        y_1        ora          app    TRUE
#  8:       1        y_1        pin          app    TRUE
#  9:       1        y_1        pin          ora    TRUE
# 10:       1        y_2        ora          app    TRUE
# 11:       1        y_2        pin          app    TRUE
# 12:       1        y_2        pin          ora    TRUE
# 13:       2        x_1        ora          app    TRUE
# 14:       2        x_1        pin          app    TRUE
# 15:       2        x_1        pin          ora    TRUE
# 16:       2        x_2        ora          app   FALSE
# 17:       2        x_2        pin          app   FALSE
# ...

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dt, aes(variable_1, i.variable_1, fill=isEqual)) +
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_grid(rowname~variable_2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This combinatorial comparison (app vs ora, ora vs pin and pin vs app) is correct, but I also want to do overall comparison (i.e. `app` vs `ora` vs `pin`).

Comment: how can we ignore the comparison with the NA column value?